# AEM sightly conditional rendering with '&&' operator

Tags: aem, sightly, htl

i'm trying to display two different set of script pased on existence of propriety model in sightly AEM.

Is this use of && operator correct?:

```
   <sly data-sly-test="${!metaFields.lastModified && metaFields.autore}" data-sly-unwrap>
something inside here...
</sly>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You may read more about sighlty on https://www.ui-experts.com/aem-sightly/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean to render the contents of the `sly` tag when `metaFields.lastModified` is falsy and `metaFields.autore` is truthy, then yes, this use of the `&&` operator is correct. If you have doubts as to how to use logical operators in HTL expressions, it's [quite clearly documented](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#1141-logical-operators).

The contents of your tag will be displayed as long as they're allowed in the current [display context](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#121-display-context). Keep in mind that this may not be the case if you're trying to render JavaScript this way.

Additionally, `data-sly-unwrap` on `sly` tags is superfluous unless you're using an early version of the language.